# get a value with different key Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, referrals

so i want to create a `refferal` code system,using firebase realtime database,but i found a difficult,how i can get all the value in key refferal?

i already have the code,but its just give me the value from my uid,

**Show below:-**

```
Query query = mDatabase.child(uid).orderByChild("refferal_status");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot movieSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserModel movie = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                if (movie.getRefferal_status().equals("akmKA")) {
                    Toast.makeText(SpinActivity.this, movie.getRefferal_status(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

> Class Model

```
 String email;
String point;
String checkin;
String limitation;
String refferal_status;

public UserModel(){

}

public UserModel(String email,String point,String checkin,String limitation,String refferal_status){
    this.email = email;
    this.point = point;
    this.checkin = checkin;
    this.limitation = limitation;
    this.refferal_status = refferal_status;
}

//setter getter here
```

}

so this is my database
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xM6g.png)

Comment: didn't get the question. you want to find a referee code is valid or not without iterating all user info ??

Comment: can you post your `model class` code!

Comment: @ShahadatHossainShaki yeah,so each user have his refferal code

Comment: @kdblue check it , i will edit

Comment: what you want @lan LaFlair? You have already got the value from your uid right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

**Note**:- `equals` expect String object .

```
 if ("akmKA".equals(movie.getRefferal_status())) {
                        Toast.makeText(SpinActivity.this, movie.getRefferal_status(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Final code

```
Query query = mDatabase.child(uid).orderByChild("refferal_status");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot movieSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserModel movie = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                if ("akmKA".equals(movie.getRefferal_status())) {
                            Toast.makeText(SpinActivity.this, movie.getRefferal_status(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```